# Boostrap 4 Login Form Responsive top height

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

This login is made with boostrap 4, actually it was a preset which I customized. Im new into boostrap and css and didn't understood how to make it responsive. The top cuts off and is not scrollable when resizing the window. It doesn't scale down.

The Login page:

```css
.login-form {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 340px;

}
.login-form form {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background: #101010;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}
.login-form h2 {
    margin: 20px 0 35px;
}
.form-control, .btn {
    min-height: 38px;
}
.btn {        
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.clearfix{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: white;
}
.text-center{
    color: white;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-weight: 200;
}

.btn{
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}

.form-control{
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: #191919;
    color: white;
    padding: 25px 20px;
}

.pull-right{
    color: #fff;
}

.btn-primary{
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-weight: 200;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#5852eb;
    border: 0;
    padding: 12px;
}

.btn-primary:hover{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#3c3986;
    border: 0;
}

.btn-primary:focus,.btn-primary.focus{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow:none !important;
}

.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,.show>.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle{color:#fff;
    background-color:#5852eb;
}

.btn-outline-primary{
    color:#5852eb;
    background-color:transparent;
    background-image:none;
    border-color:#5852eb
}

.btn-outline-primary:hover{
    color:#5852eb;
    background-color:#5852eb;
    border-color:#5852eb;
}

.btn:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}


input[type="text"], textarea {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow:none !important;
}

input[type="password"], textarea {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow:none !important;
}

input[type="email"], textarea {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow:none !important;
}

.g-recaptcha {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    transform:scale(0.93);
    transform-origin:0 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Hash.ms | Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>


</head>
<body style="background-color:#0D0D0D; ">
<div class="login-form ">
    
    <form action="Login.html" method="post">
        <h2 class="text-center">LOGIN</h2>       
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="2FA code" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <label class="pull-left checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
            <a href="#" class="pull-right">Forgot Password?</a>
        </div> 
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI" data-theme="dark"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Log in</button>
        </div>
</form>
    <p class="text-center"><a href="Signup.html" style="color: white;">Create an Account</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The top just cuts off, I can't scroll either.

Comment: why are you redefining `form-control` in your css? that is part of bootstrap 4

Comment: please check, you have CDN of bootstrap `3.3.7`

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Change

```
 .login-form {
    position: absolute;
```
to
```
.login-form {
    position: fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user a div .container and insert your form there, bootstrap have his own classes to make responsive your content (.col-xl-4 .col-md-4 .col-sm-4) you can read more about this here [bootstrap responsive-breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints)

Verify your CDN, this is a CDN for bootstrap 4

[Bootstrap CDN](http://%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css%22%20integrity=%22sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO%22%20crossorigin=%22anonymous%22%3E)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to read about the GRID SYSYEM:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/

And also you could add like a card:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/card/

Obviously, you have to use you same css file.